# Was it common to publish the times of voyages in the newspapers?

Tags: short-stories, historical-context, r-austin-freeman, dr-thorndyke

In "[The Case of the White Footprints](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks14/1402921h.html#c1)" in *Dr. Thorndyke's Case-Book* (1923) by R. Austin Freeman, a woman was talking to a detective about a situation in her hotel, saying:

> "I noticed that she seemed very nervous and upset when she got the letters from hospital, and still more so when the last letter came. Of course, I don't know what he said to her in those letters. It may be that he had heard something about Mr. Bergson, and threatened to take some action. Of course, I can't say. I only know that she was very nervous and restless, and **when we saw in the paper four days ago that the ship he would be coming by had arrived in Liverpool** she seemed dreadfully upset. And she got worse and worse until—well, until last night."

Was it common for newspapers to report the arrivals of ships?

Comment: My local paper (The San Francisco Chronicle) was still publishing shipping arrivals and departures in the 1990s. They may well still be doing it today.

Comment: You can also google "<port> shipping arrivals" and see that Google has special handling for this request to give a summary of upcoming arrivals.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  It would be back page news but it was crucial to businesses to know such information.

[Here are some samples.](https://www.theshipslist.com/ships/Arrivals/index.htm)

Comment: I searched a lot for an example like that. Thank you so much.